# Making editable header text, won't work!

Tags: javascript, xampp

I have a header message that is brought in from another file (message.txt), and I'm making a text box that you can edit. (I will add the part where it makes it permanent later on.)
It is changing to nothing.

(E: "This is the header!" to "")

This is the code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change(text)
{
//document.forms["f1"].elements["ta"].value="Hi!";
//document.f1.ta.value="Hi!";
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML='<h2 class="hmsg">'+text+'</h2>';
}
function getText()
{
return document.getElementById("ta").value;
}
function all()
{
change(getText())
}
</script>
<form name="f1">
<input type="text" value="Enter your message here!" id="ta"/>
<input type="button" value="          " onclick='all()'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can clarify what is not working as you expect. I expanded your code into a working example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function change(text)
{
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML='<h2 class="hmsg">'+text+'</h2>';
}
function getText()
{
return document.getElementById("ta").value;
}
function all()
{
  change(getText())
}
</script>
<form action="#">
<div id="msg">
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" value="Enter your message here!" id="ta"/>
<input type="button" value="          " onclick='all()'/>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Changing the content of the `<div>` with id `msg` works here.

Comment: You should consider using a JavaScript library to simplify client-side scripting for you. Libs like jQuery were really a boost to productivity. Additionally, try to be standards conformant...